# D3.js path transition not working

Tags: svg, d3.js, path, transition

I want to draw a path, and then change its coordinates. The following code is not working ( url: http://porwal.info/direct/d3demo/line.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() { startDrawing(); });

function startDrawing() {
   var data = [
   { x : 50, y : 50},
   { x : 80, y : 40},
   { x : 100, y : 500}
   ];

   var container = d3.select("body");

   var vis = container.append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", 200)
      .attr("height", 200);

   var d3line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d){return d.x;})
      .y(function(d){return d.y;});

   vis.append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", d3line(data))
      .style("stroke-width", 2)
      .style("stroke", "blue")
      .style("fill", "none");

   data = [
   { x : 50, y : 50},
   { x : 300, y : 10},
   { x : 100, y : 500}
   ];

vis.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("d", d3line(data));
};
```

The result is that it just draws the initial path and then does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're transitioning on `vis`, which is a selection containing the `svg` and not the `path` element. It's setting the `d` attribute on the SVG correctly, but of course that doesn't have any effect. It works correctly if you select the `path` element.

```
vis.select("path").transition()...
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dtzsfhbb/).

Comment: Thanks. Silly me, I should say!